# How to group by items and calculate the quantities after calculation MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a set of order items placed in my table. These order items are generated from 2 order types. The sales order and the purchase order. One sales order can have multiple purchase orders to fulfill the quantities. I want a way to calculate the remaining quantity to fulfill the next sales order in database level.

this is my order table

```
+----+------------+------------+------------------------+--------+------------+
| id | order_type | order_from | base_order_if_purchase | amount | status     |
+----+------------+------------+------------------------+--------+------------+
| 1  | sales      | 1          | null                   | 8500   | incomplete |
+----+------------+------------+------------------------+--------+------------+
| 2  | purchase   | 1          | 1                      | 2500   | complete   |
+----+------------+------------+------------------------+--------+------------+
| 3  | purchase   | 1          | 1                      | 5000   | complete   |
+----+------------+------------+------------------------+--------+------------+
```

The sales order will be completed after the quantities has been fulfilled in all purchase orders.

This is my order_items table

```
+----+----------+---------+----------+--------+
| id | order_id | item_id | quantity | type   |
+----+----------+---------+----------+--------+
| 1  | 1        | 1       | 10       | Accept |
+----+----------+---------+----------+--------+
| 2  | 1        | 2       | 15       | Accept |
+----+----------+---------+----------+--------+
| 3  | 1        | 3       | 20       | Reject |
+----+----------+---------+----------+--------+
| 4  | 2        | 1       | 5        | Accept |
+----+----------+---------+----------+--------+
| 5  | 2        | 2       | 10       | Accept |
+----+----------+---------+----------+--------+
| 6  | 2        | 4       | 10       | Accept |
+----+----------+---------+----------+--------+
| 7  | 3        | 1       | 2        | Accept |
+----+----------+---------+----------+--------+
| 9  | 3        | 2       | 5        | Accept |
+----+----------+---------+----------+--------+
```

Order 1 is the sales Order. Order 2 & 3 are purchase orders. I want to calculate the remaining quantities of the items. Some new items also can be added in the purchase order which are not in the sales order.

```
Accepted Order 1 items - (Order 2 items + Order 3 items)
```

So the result should be

```
+---------+----------+
| item_id | quantity |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 3        |
+---------+----------+
| 2       | 0        |
+---------+----------+
| 4       | 10       |
+---------+----------+
```

I'm currently doing this by selecting the items in each order and performing the calculation in application level.

Comment: there must be a field/column  that marks an order as sell or purchase, or you have a order tbale that holds that information, so you must post that too

Comment: Yes it is stored in order table. I'll post that too.

Comment: order table added

Comment: the column order_type  should be a Itinint type,and with another table, you would save a lot of space in the long run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should normalize your tbales
the columns order_items.`type` and orders.`order_type` should be Tinyint  and you need also two small tables ordertype and orderItemtype that canes joined when the text is needed

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE order_items (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `order_id` INTEGER,
  `item_id` INTEGER,
  `quantity` INTEGER,
  `type` VARCHAR(6)
);

INSERT INTO order_items
  (`id`, `order_id`, `item_id`, `quantity`, `type`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '1', '10', 'Accept'),
  ('2', '1', '2', '15', 'Accept'),
  ('3', '1', '3', '20', 'Reject'),
  ('4', '2', '1', '5', 'Accept'),
  ('5', '2', '2', '10', 'Accept'),
  ('6', '2', '4', '10', 'Accept'),
  ('7', '3', '1', '2', 'Accept'),
  ('9', '3', '2', '5', 'Accept'),
  ('10', '4', '1', '5', 'Accept'),
  ('11', '4', '2', '10', 'Accept');

CREATE TABLE orders (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `order_type` VARCHAR(8),
  `order_from` INTEGER,
  `base_order_if_purchase` VARCHAR(4),
  `amount` INTEGER,
  `status` VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO orders
  (`id`, `order_type`, `order_from`, `base_order_if_purchase`, `amount`, `status`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'sales', '1', NULL, '8500', 'incomplete'),
  ('2', 'purchase', '1', '1', '2500', 'complete'),
  ('3', 'purchase', '1', '1', '5000', 'complete'),
  ('4', 'sales', '1', NULL, '7000', 'incomplete');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    `row_num`,`item_id`
    ,SUM(`sumitem`)
   FROM 
   (SELECT 
         `item_id`,o.`row_num` , IF (`order_type` = 'sales',`quantity`,-`quantity`) sumitem
    FROM order_items o_i 
   INNER JOIN (  SELECT o.`id`, o.`order_type`,row_num
  FROM `orders` o INNER JOIN (
  SELECT `id`, @rn := @rn + 1  row_num FROM orders ,(SELECT @rn := 0) a WHERE `base_order_if_purchase` IS NULL ORDER BY `id`) o1 
  ON o.`id` =  o1.`id` OR o.`base_order_if_purchase` =  o1.`id`) o ON o_i.`order_id` = o.`id`
   WHERE o_i.`type` = 'Accept') t1
  GROUP BY `row_num`,`item_id`;

| row_num | item_id | SUM(`sumitem`) |
| ------- | ------- | -------------- |
| 1       | 1       | 3              |
| 1       | 2       | 0              |
| 1       | 4       | -10            |
| 2       | 1       | 5              |
| 2       | 2       | 10             |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/31)

Comment: Hi. I just run your code. I want the result based on 1 sales order. If there are 2 sales orders this query gives wrong result. I updated the fiddle data. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/27

Comment: what should the result be then, please write it as comment also in the fiddle and link it new

Comment: your answer is correct for the 1st sales order (and the 2nd & 3rd purchase orders). If I add another sales order results gonna change. I have commented the lines in the schema (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/28). What I meant was the final results (item_id & sum) should be for one sales order.

Comment: For that you need another column to diffrentiate the sales, save it in your table as you can see, in the example, it is quite complcated to get it

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm running mysql 5.7. The ROW_NUMBER() OVER function is not working. I'll try it in another way. :(

Comment: @camille  no problem  i changed it to mysql 5-7

Comment: thank you very much